# Is there a reliable workaround for onDisappear() not working within .sheet() or .popover() in SwiftUI on macOS?

Tags: macos, swiftui

I'm building an app that shares quite a bit of SwiftUI code between its iOS and macOS targets.  On iOS, `onDisappear` seems to work reliably on `Views`.  However, on macOS, `onDisappear` doesn't get called if the `View` is inside a `sheet` or `popover`.

The following code illustrates the concept:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var textShown = true
    @State private var showSheet = false
    @State private var showPopover = false

    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            Button("Toggle text") {
                self.textShown.toggle()
            }
            if textShown {
                Text("Text").onDisappear {
                    print("Text disappearing")
                }
            }
            Button("Toggle sheet") {
                self.showSheet.toggle()
            }.sheet(isPresented: $showSheet, onDismiss: {
                print("On dismiss")
            }) {
                VStack {
                    Button("Close sheet") {
                        self.showSheet = false
                    }
                }.onDisappear {
                    print("Sheet disappearing")
                }
            }

            Button("Toggle popover") {
                self.showPopover.toggle()
            }.popover(isPresented: $showPopover) {
                VStack {
                    Text("popover")
                }.onDisappear {
                    print("Popover disappearing")
                }
            }
        }
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, maxHeight: .infinity)
    }
}
```

Note that `onDisappear` works fine on the `Text` component at the beginning of the `VStack` but the other two `onDisappear` calls don't get executed on macOS.

One workaround I've found is to attach an `ObservableObject` to the `View` and use `deinit` to call cleanup code.  However, this isn't a great solution for two reasons:

1) With the `popover` example, there's a significant delay between the dismissal of the `popover` and the deist call (although it works quickly on `sheets`)
2) I haven't had any crashes on macOS with this approach, but on iOS, `deinit` have been unreliable in SwiftUI doing anything but trivial code -- holding references to my data store, app state, etc. have had crashes.

Here's the basic approach I used for the `deinit` strategy:

```
class DeinitObject : ObservableObject {
    deinit {
        print("Deinit obj")
    }
}

struct ViewWithObservableObject : View {
    @ObservedObject private var deinitObj = DeinitObject()

    var body: some View {
        Text("Deinit view")
    }
}
```

Also, I would have thought I could use the `onDismiss` parameter of the `sheet` call, but that doesn't get called either on macOS.  And, it's not an available parameter of `popover`.

All of this is using Xcode 11.4.1 and macOS 10.15.3.

Any solutions for good workarounds?

Comment: Hitting the same issue on iOS 13.3; this is just terrible from Apple.